# ¿Por qué los tipos de datos primitivos tienen un tamaño fijo?

Tags: lenguaje-agnóstico

En algunos de los lenguajes de programación, normalmente [c](/questions/tagged/c), [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) y [java](/questions/tagged/java), los tipos de datos enteros son `int`, `short` y `long`.
El tipo de datos `int` suele ser de 32 bits. El tipo de datos `short` normalmente es más pequeño que el tipo de datos `int` y el tipo de datos `long` normalmente es más grande que el tipo de datos `int`.

El primer *bit* de un tipo de dato entero es el signo *bit*.
Un número negativo comienza con '1' y un número no negativo comienza con '0'.

Por lo tanto, un tipo de datos de *32 bits normalmente* almacena números en el rango `-(2^31)` a `(2^31 - 1)`.

- ¿Por qué no podemos tener un tipo de datos de tamaño ilimitado, de modo que podamos almacenar un rango ilimitado de números?

<sub>Traducción del [inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66079316)</sub>

<sub>[Traducción en portugués](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/559752/por-que-os-tipos-de-dados-primitivos-s%c3%a3o-fixos-em-tamanho)</sub>

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esta pregunta suena interesante.. tambien suena a algo basado en opiniones.... tenes tipos de datos mas grande.. que tan grande queres el numero? ademas, los numeros vienen basados por los tamaños de los registros, ojo con eso... como esperas que una computadora con registros de 64 bits haga calculos con numeros mas grandes que  algo que ocupe 2 registros por ejemplo?

Comment: Simplemente el procesador puede trabajar bien con números de ese tamaño. Sino puedes preguntarle al creador del lenguaje por qué lo quiso hacer así. Y en C/C++ el tamaño de los tipos varía según el procesador, el sistema operativo y el compilador.

Comment: Como dice @Mateo, esas limitaciones vienen dadas, en parte, por el procesador. Muchas operaciones de cálculo numérico se corresponden con instrucciones del propio procesador. Un tipo de dato numérico con un rango indeterminado (por ejemplo 1024 bytes), requeriría su propia implementación software para las operaciones más básicas (suma, resta, multiplicación y división). Si necesitas un tipo de dato así de grande, tendrás que implementarlo por tu cuenta o buscar una librería que ya se haya pegado con todos esos problemas

Comment: Dicho esto, no entiendo el motivo para cerrar esta pregunta

Comment: @eferion te animas a meterle una respuesta? yo tampoco entendi el cierre por que faltan detalles... me daba mas a opiniones, pero con retoques se arreglaba...

Comment: @gbianchi justamente ahora estaba escribiendo en meta XD

Comment: Actualmente esta pregunta incluye múltiples preguntas en una. Debería centrarse en un solo problema.

Comment: @RuslanLópez opino lo mismo es una pregunta muy abierta ... esto se presta para confusiones al momento de determinar el diseño de diferentes lenguajes o de estudiarlos ...

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Las limitaciones de las que hablas tienen que ver con la forma en la que están diseñados los lenguajes de programación.

Un lenguaje de programación surge de la conveniencia de evitar el uso de ensamblador o el lenguaje máquina para los desarrollos que no requieran su uso expreso.

Sin embargo, aunque se intente evitar el uso de ensamblador, el lenguaje de programación tiene una serie de limitaciones impuestas por el procesador que va a ejecutar el código.

Los procesadores actuales son de 64 bits, es decir, son capaces de manejar de forma nativa información de 64 bits (en algunos casos incluso pueden llegar manejar 128 bits), pero más allá de eso el sistema no posee ningún hardware que le permita manejar valores más grandes.

Es debido a esta dependencia del procesador que algunos lenguajes, como C y C++, que no tienen realmente un tipo fijo para los datos, así. De hecho, si consultas el último [borrador](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental) de C++, verás que el estándar te habla de un tamaño mínimo para cada tipo de dato. El máximo viene dado, normalmente, por la arquitectura del procesador.

Si alguien necesita un tipo de dato numérico que use más bits de los que soporta el procesador, entonces tendrá que programar ese soporte por software. No es una operación imposible pero sí es engorrosa.

Si no estás dispuesto a programar toda esa lógica, tendrás que buscar una librería que te proporcione esta funcionalidad.

Comment: puedes darnos una breve representación de tu argumento en los lenguajes de programación: Java, Python, C/C++, C#
Kotlin,
Swift,
PHP,
Javascript,
Objective-C,
TypeScript,
R,
Fortran,
LISP, 
COBOL,
Pascal,
Perl,
VB.Net,
Visual Basic,
SQL,
Ruby,
Delphi,
Go,
Assembly y D

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 pues me temo que no, no domino todos esos lenguajes y cada uno se ha creado bajo una premisa distinta. Lo que está claro es que el que te ofrece un tipo que supera la palabra de la arquitectura del procesador es porque hace cálculos por software. Normalmente esta funcionalidad viene dada en forma de librería de terceros, pero por ejemplo Java trae la clase BigInteger que ya ofrece esta funcionalidad ... via software, por supuesto

Answer (score 5):

Argumentando sobre esta pregunta:
**¿Por qué no podemos tener un tipo de datos de tamaño ilimitado, de modo que podamos almacenar un rango ilimitado de números?**

1. No depende del lenguaje al 100%.
2. La dependencia recae sobre:
   -A. Arquitectura del Hardware.
   -B. Diseño del Lenguaje.

**A.** Al momento de diseñar un lenguaje de programación dependemos siempre del hardware sobre el que se ejecuta; y ningún hardware tiene Procesador, memoria, almacenamiento ilimitados; esto es nuestra limitante y debemos trabajar sobre lo que existe en la actualidad o crearlo.

**B.** Cuando se Diseña un lenguaje. lo que se busca es evitar el lenguaje de maquina, o evitar el tener que programar a tan bajo nivel, entonces el diseño del lenguaje dependerá directamente del hardware y evitar la perdida del control del mismo.

---

**Por que tu pregunta es muy amplia:**

Entonces dependiendo del diseño del Lenguaje (que son mucho) y sobre que Hardware corre, podrás crear datos primitivos de mayor o menor tamaño:

Como por ejemplo programar C para un procesador de 32 bit y uno de 64 bit.

Luego tenemos un solo lenguaje con capacidades distintas dependiendo de la plataforma. o tambien podemos tener lenguajes específicos para ciertas plataformas o hardware.

---

**Respuesta:**

Por que existe el Overflow y hay que evitarlo. [Link](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer)
Perdida de control de recursos del Hardware.

Ahora tu pregunta es muy amplia ya que **NO estas dándonos un escenario preciso**, exacto en donde quieres conocer por que no *podamos almacenar un rango ilimitado de números* ya que la respuesta puede variar del lenguaje, su diseño y del hardware en el que se ejecuta.

---

**Como cierre:** Pero te aseguro que el día que podamos almacenar datos en el vacío del espacio entonces podríamos decir que tenemos espacio de almacenamiento infinito para tus números.

Comment: Tú respondes a la pregunta misma, dentro de lo que dices que explica por qué es muy amplia. Ahora, ir a reducir al absurdo las respuestas ajenas me parece desafortunado.

Comment: a la comunidad le gusta, aunque se pase por lo eggs las normas ... solo hay que fluir ... no lo tomes a pecho ...

Comment: Para nada. Si ni siquiera fue un comentario pa mí, yo aca vengo como embajador de la buena onda. ;)

Answer (score 5):

El Universo visible tiene 10^80 partículas. Por tanto, para representar cualquier valor material en este Universo necesitas a lo más 80 dígitos decimales de largo.

Para cualquier problema de la vida real (construir un puente, levantar un edificio, diseñar un motor) te basta con 4 dígitos decimales de precisión.

Hasta mediados del siglo XX la Humanidad se las arreglaba con reglas de cálculo (tres dígitos de precisión máximo) para todas su obras de ingeniería.

Así que la razón es: con los tipos de datos que tenemos alcanza para cualquier aplicación práctica.

Construir computadores de precisión arbitraría agrega costos y complejidades al diseño sin rendir ningún beneficio.

Answer (score 0):

Ampliando las respuestas anteriores me gustaría decir que en **C#** y **Java** puedes trabajar con el tipo de datos **BigInteger**, el cual te permitirá trabajar con números inmensamente grandes. **BigInteger** sobrecarga los operadores numéricos estándar para permitirte realizar operaciones matemáticas básicas como suma, resta, división, multiplicación y negación unaria. También puede usar los operadores numéricos estándar para comparar dos **BigInteger** entre sí y también admite los operadores a nivel de bits, tales como **Or**, **XOr**, **And**, **desplazamiento a la izquierda** y **desplazamiento a la derecha**.

En **Java**, además, existe el tipo de datos **BigDecimal** el cual sirve para representar números decimales con una precisión inmensamente grande.